# Mascapsul MQTT IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mqtt

for the first time I'm developing IOS application  for IOT using "MQTT" of framework "Moscapsule"
but, the problem was, I have written connection code as per the frame work but it is not connecting ,here my code

```
let RandomId : String = "IOS_\(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString)"

    // set MQTT Client Configuration
    let mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: RandomId, host:      "http://13.232.153.138", port: 1883, keepAlive: 60)

    mqttConfig.mqttAuthOpts = MQTTAuthOpts(username: "byname", password: "password")

let mqttClient = MQTT.newConnection(mqttConfig)
    print(mqttClient)
    print("MQTT Connection Status  : \(String(describing: mqttClient.isConnected))")
    print("MQTT is running  : \(String(describing: mqttClient.isRunning))")


}
```

console message was:::
MQTT Connection Status  : false

Comment: You probably need your `mqttClient` to be a property, not a local variable otherwise it will be released as soon as the function returns

Comment: MQTT Connection Status  : Optional(false)
MQTT is running  : true

Comment: var mqttClient: MQTTClient? declared a property then also same error.  MQTT Connection Status  : Optional(false)
MQTT is running  : true  ,please do the needful

Comment: You are printing the status before the connection is made. The connection occurs asynchronously. Your prints excite immediately.  You need to implement the on connection callback

Comment: okay thank you,If you are having code can you please help me out by sending over here.

Comment: You can see the code in the first example under "Quick Start" on the [Github](https://github.com/flightonary/Moscapsule) page